# Go and execute else statement from if statement C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

Below are the if-else conditions statements I am using. I was thinking to remove code duplication inside //Statements 2

```
if (true)
{
    List<string> usersList=getUsersList();
    if(usersList.Length > 0){   
    //Statements 1
    ..............
    }
    else{
    //Statements 2
    .............
    }
}
else
{
    //Statements 2
    .............
}
```

In the above code Need to repeat **Statements 2**. Is there way to send execution to main else loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
bool runSecondBlock = !firstCondition;
if (firstCondition)
{
  List<string> usersList=getUsersList();
  if(usersList.Length > 0){   
    //Statements 1
    ..............
  }
  else {
    runSecondBlock = true;
  }
}
if (runSecondBlock)
{
    //Statements 2
    .............
}
```

Comment: This could do with some commentary, but it is my preferred choice, even though we could use anonymous delegates or actions, using deliberate flags makes in complex desicion logic makes the code very easy to test and maintain. Even allows a good deal of space for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [conditional logical operator &&](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-) to accomplish this, but take care, if your decision tree becomes more complicated, it can get messy rather quickly.

```
if (condition1 && condition2) //both need to be "true" to execute statements 1
{
   //Statements 1
}

else
{
   //Statements 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Stefan. making condition2 as external function to give excepted value. But unable to execute this always should execute based on conditon1. Is there any way using of GO TO.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I can update the example, but I need the names you are using. In your question you only use `true` as condition.